# How do I request organization approval for OAuth Apps in GitHub, really?

Tags: github, oauth

[The instructions that GitHub gives to request organization approval for OAuth Apps](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-your-membership-in-organizations/requesting-organization-approval-for-oauth-apps) are clear, readable, concise, and wrong.

In particular, Step 4 reads “In the list of applications, click the name of the OAuth App you'd like to request access for.”  Doing that brings you to a summary page for that app:

[image: The connections page.]

Step 5 is “Next to the organization you'd like the OAuth App to access, click **Request access**.”  There is no list of organizations on that page, or the previous one.

Does anyone know how to actually do this?

Comment: I have not figured this out either. If I do, I'll be sure to post an answer :)

Comment: Hmm... I've noticed that at least one app does show an organization list, but not all of them.